# Layout issues since iOS 8

Tags: ios, layout, ios8

I have a simple view with 3 blocks horizontally. Each block is a small image and 2 labels and between the blocks is a small vertical bar. In the resource they are placed one after the other. I'm using the following code to place the individual images and labels at the correct location:

```
- (void)layoutRankingFields
{
    // remove lines
    for (UIView *subview in [self subviews])
    {
        if (subview.tag == LINE1_TAG || subview.tag == LINE2_TAG)
        {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    // we need a separator space on all sides of the three groups
    float totalWeeks = self.imageWeeks.frame.size.width + [self widthForLabel:self.nrWeeks] + [self widthForLabel:self.labelWeeks];
    float totalHighest = self.imageHighest.frame.size.width + [self widthForLabel:self.nrHighest] + [self widthForLabel:self.labelHighest];
    float totalYear = self.imageYear.frame.size.width + [self widthForLabel:self.nrYear] + [self widthForLabel:self.labelYear];
    float widthSeparator = (self.frame.size.width - (totalWeeks + totalHighest + totalYear + 8 /*spacing between nr and label field and 2 separator lines*/)) / 6;

    // now reposition all fields
    // weeks
    float floatX = widthSeparator;
    [self repositionSubView:self.imageWeeks xpos:floatX];
    floatX = floatX + self.imageWeeks.frame.size.width;
    [self repositionSubView:self.nrWeeks xpos:floatX];
    floatX = floatX + [self widthForLabel:self.nrWeeks] + 2;
    [self repositionSubView:self.labelWeeks xpos:floatX];

    // vertical separator line
    floatX = floatX + [self widthForLabel:self.labelWeeks] + widthSeparator;
    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake)(floatX, 0, 1, self.bounds.size.height)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [line setTag:LINE1_TAG];
    [self addSubview:line];
    [line release];

    // highest
    floatX = floatX + 1 + widthSeparator;
    [self repositionSubView:self.imageHighest xpos:floatX];
    floatX = floatX + self.imageHighest.frame.size.width + 2;
    [self repositionSubView:self.nrHighest xpos:floatX];
    floatX = floatX + [self widthForLabel:self.nrHighest] + 2;
    [self repositionSubView:self.labelHighest xpos:floatX];

    // vertical separator line
    floatX = floatX + [self widthForLabel:self.labelHighest] + widthSeparator;
    line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake)(floatX, 0, 1, self.bounds.size.height)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:224/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [line setTag:LINE2_TAG];
    [self addSubview:line];
    [line release];

    // year
    floatX = floatX + 1 + widthSeparator;
    [self repositionSubView:self.imageYear xpos:floatX];
    floatX = floatX + self.imageYear.frame.size.width;
    [self repositionSubView:self.nrYear xpos:floatX];
    floatX = floatX + [self widthForLabel:self.nrYear] + 2;
    [self repositionSubView:self.labelYear xpos:floatX];
}

- (void)repositionSubView:(UIView*)view xpos:(float)x
{
    CGRect frame = view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = x;
    view.frame = frame;
    view.hidden = FALSE;
    [view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

However, when running on iOS 8 the last block is placed over the preceding label. The vertical bar is placed properly. I've added some logging to see the values calculated and they are the same between iOS 7 and 8.

Any suggestions?

Comment: After more investigation it seems that the `repositionSubView` is not properly executed on iOS 8. I've added this function to the original question.

Comment: More info: when I press Home to close the app and then open the app again, the layout visibly flips into place.